com.apple.xpc.launchd's log getting filled with "denied lookup: name = com.apple.audio.audiohald … Sandbox restriction"
The /var/log/com.apple.xpc.launchd/launchd.log file on a Mac computer (Mac Mini M1) is getting lots of the following lines (about 4160 per minute, which is 66 per second):
2024-10-21 16:28:09.167884 (gui/2001 [100017]) <Warning>: denied lookup: name = com.apple.audio.audiohald, flags = 0x9, requestor = Google Chrome H[772], error = 159: Sandbox restriction
2024-10-21 16:28:09.167952 (gui/2001 [100017]) <Warning>: denied lookup: name = com.apple.audio.audiohald, flags = 0x9, requestor = Slack Helper (G[822], error = 159: Sandbox restriction

I do have the same error lines on some other Mac computers, but not as much/fast (2 per second).
I suspect it's "eating" some of my IO and slowing down the computer (as well as using the SSD).
What does it means? How can I fix/disable/ignore them?
If it's coming from a misconfiguration of macOS: Is there a way/command to fix it?
Version:

macOS is version 14.2.1 (build 23C71).
Slack is version 4.40.133 (the latest available as of 2024-10-21)
Chrome is version 130.0.6723.59 (the latest available as of 2024-10-21)


I’m going to grit my teeth and resist the urge to say you should just get rid of that crappy spyware browser. Does it have access to the microphone in the Privacy & Security settings? If not, please grant that access—temporarily—and see whether there’s any change.
